# How to align text inside pie chart?

Tags: xetex, pstricks, charts

I'm creating pie chart using code below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(4,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40},chartSep=10pt,shadow,shadowsize=3pt]{\above,\below}{}{3}
\bfseries%
\rput(psChartI1){TEXTA \above \%}\rput(psChartI2){TEXTB \below \%}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
```

Currently TEXTA & TEXTB are aligned towards circumference, is there any way to center align this text?

UPDATE: (with MWE);

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(4,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40},chartSep=10pt,shadow,shadowsize=3pt]{30,70}{}{3}
\bfseries%
\rput(psChartI1){TEXTA 30 \%}\rput(psChartI2){TEXTB 70 \%}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with MWE (minimal working example). `\rput` has an optional argument to specify the anchor.

Comment: MWE updated in the question.

Comment: Herbert's answer is much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the distance of the inner chart node to 0.5:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(4,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40},chartSep=10pt,chartNodeI=0.5,%%%%%
         shadow,shadowsize=3pt]{30,70}{}{3}
\rput(psChartI1){\bf TEXTA 30\%}
\rput(psChartI2){\bf TEXTB 70\%}
%\psdots(psChartI1)(psChartI2)%% for a test
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really don't understand why you still use a command (`\bf`) that has been declared obsolete twenty years ago. If you want to use it in your own documents, fine; I find it wrong to use it in a public place where we are expected to teach proper usage of LaTeX.

Comment: What has PSTricks to do with `\bf`? Try changing `article` into `memoir` and see the result.

Comment: Thank You, it's working perfectly for ratio of 30,70; Is there any way to make it generic (to make center align for any values ex: 10:90 , 5:95, 50,50 and so on)?

Comment: @PawanMude: see my edit. I set the relative distance of the inner node to 0.5

Comment: Why do we need to load `pst-node` when using `(*x {\f(x)})` syntax?

Comment: @PGFTricks: It is _not_ needed

Comment: I see. I forgot to enable `\SpecialCoor`. It  should be enabled by default because I think none use slow computers nowadays. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=0+15}{24}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psChart[userColor={black!10,black!40},chartSep=10pt,shadow,shadowsize=3pt]{30,70}{}{3}
\bfseries
\rput{\i}(1.5;54){TEXTA 30 \%}
\rput{\i}(1.5;234){TEXTB 70 \%}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Animation proves that the labels are centered.

Comment: Thank You PGFTricks for sharing answer. It's working as desired.